# Birt 4.6 intergration with Wildfly 10.1.0

Tags: wildfly, birt, wildfly-10

I want to integrate Birt Report 4.6 engine with Wildfly 10.1.0

I have created the "org.eclipse" module added in the application dependency.
and When I try to open the report I get some error.
test.rptdesign is in test.war file

test.rptdesign

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.22" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 3.7.1.v20110905 Build &lt;3.7.1.v20110913-1734></property>
    <property name="units">in</property>
    <method name="initialize"><![CDATA[importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
importPackage(Packages.java.util);

//code here
```

The following items have errors:

```
ReportDesign (id = 1):
- There are errors evaluating script "importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
importPackage(Packages.java.util);

birt.core.JavascriptCommonError ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: There are errors evaluating script "importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
importPackage(Packages.java.util);

Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.CoreException: There are errors evaluating script "importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
importPackage(Packages.java.util);
```

How to make java and my custom jar available while compilation in birt?
I have added custom jar as dependency in the manifest file of birt.war still it does get custom as well as java.lang and java.util package

**Update:**

Now I came to know that there is no problem with java packages
but When I try to create an object of my class in .rptDesign file

My structure is like this

**org.eclipse** is the **module** in Wildfly and **test.jar** is deployed on Wildfly which has my class.
So Now I guess org.eclipse which has eclipse runtime is not able to access the class of test.jar which is deployed but I have added dependency of test.jar on birt.war